# Got error when trying to register for GCM push parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

first - sorry for my english.
im trying to use PARSE to send push notification. i succeed to save user on user class and installation class is to updated when i run my app. 
when im trying to send push notification it says thst i have recipients.
i create my push and sending it.
in the push details it says that i have Subscribers.
but no notification on the device.
in the eclipse ive got error
`"06-08 09:29:30.338: E/com.parse.GcmRegistrar(31999): Got error when trying to register for GCM push"`
how can i fix this?
it would be great if someone can help me.
tnx
tamar

**EDIT**:

logcat attached:
http://pastebin.com/8d9ygq1x

Comment: Can you include the full LogCat (and not just one line)?

Comment: i cant because "You need at least 10 reputation to post images."

Comment: added a Pastebin link

Comment: `com.parse.ParseException: at least one ID field (installationId,deviceToken) must be specified in this operation` looks like you are missing something. Can you post your registration code?

Comment: I have got those three lines:                       Parse.initialize(this, "CWuzkEHJ2JwHIjYXdhscILiGDJ8IHesoRNXmzXam",
    "8Mcfm0xbq1WFBrW4bEKglN2f2b33fmzm0uspKaFF");
  PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
  ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();      isnt it enough?

Comment: ok, after a few checks i underatand that in nexus devices it works, i get the push. but in galaxy i cant get any pushes